# VBA: add a row in excel only if there's a value in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using the macro below so when I make a change in cells from column B, it adds a Line. I'd like to know how to change the code so it only adds a line when there's content in the cell and not when I make a change (like erasing content from that same cell).
Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Test if change is in column B and only one cell changed
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("B")) Is Nothing And _
            Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        Target.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown      'Insert row below data entry

        'Target.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown       'Insert row above data entry

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to check if a cell is empty, such as ...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Test if change is in column B and only one cell changed
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("B")) Is Nothing And _
        Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

    If len(Target)>0 then
          Target.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown      'Insert row below data entry
         'Target.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown       'Insert row above data entry
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Or you could `Isempty(Target)` or `target<>vbnullstring`.

Comment: Many thanks! One last thing, how do I add a function that when I change the content of the cell it doesnt add a line either?

Comment: One ask per question please.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to check the if the target value is empty is to use `Target.Value`

```
If Target.Value <> "" Then
  Target.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End If
```